# Linq Contains operator doesnt work

Tags: .net, linq, nhibernate, where-clause, contains

Met a problem on linq use.
When i use `.Where(m=> m.Name == "name")` it works but when i use `.Where(m=> m.Name.Contains("name"))` its not.

my query is

`return summary.JoinAlias(s => s.District, () => district, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).Where(() => district.Name. == "ALEK");` <- works

`return summary.JoinAlias(s => s.District, () => district, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).Where(() => district.Name.Contains("ALEK"));` <- not works

Comment: What do you mean by does not work?

Comment: It give me this exception: -  $exception {"Unrecognised method call: System.String:Boolean Contains(System.String)"} System.Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`JoinAlias`** is a part of `QueryOver` syntax. For `Contains()` we should use this:

```
return summary
    .JoinAlias(s => s.District, () => district
                  , NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(() => district.Name) // here we say what to restrict
        .IsLike("ALEK", MatchMode.Anywhere)  // and we say to use LIKE
    ;                                        // matching as: %ALEK%
```

Check:

- [16.3. Additional Restrictions](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-additionalrestrictions)